# how to make function which related comboboxes option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

in my html page there are three form input has been related each other.
first input as combobox with option:

- TCA
- Intasept
  second and third input as text type.

if first input fill is "TCA" when user input in second input "01" so in third input automaticly filled by "1-120".
if first input fill is "intasept" when user input in second input "01" in third input automaticly fille by "1-32".

on simple logic.

- first input = "TCA" (selected option by user).
- second input = "01" (manually input by user).
- third input = "1-120" (automaticly input).

this will continue with interval 120. ex:

- second input: 02:      03 and so on.
- third input : 121-240: 241-360 and so on.

if in first input = Intasept (selected option by user).

- second input = 01 (manually input by user).
- third input = 1-32 (automaticly input).
- this will continue with interval 32.

ex:

- second input : 02:    03    and so on.
- third input  : 32-64: 65-96  and so on.

help me how to make this function in javascript.
this, what i have tried but this not run

```
var interval, step;
$("#first").change(function (e) {
    if (this.option:selected) interval = { // map of input value attributes to interval values
        "TCA": 120,
        "intasept": 32
    }[this.value];
    update();
});
$("#secondInput").on("change keyup input paste", function (e) {
    step = parseInt(this.value, 10);
    update();
});

function update() {
    if (isNaN(interval) || isNaN(step)) return;
    $("#thirdInput").val(((interval * step + 1)-interval) + "-" + ((interval * step + interval)-interval));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n8pSt/

Comment: I'm the only one that does not know how that `if` call works? I can't understand what do you want to do when `change` triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/QXFKL/5/

```
if (this.option:selected) interval = { // map of input value attributes to interval values
    "TCA": 120,
    "intasept": 32
}[this.value];
```

but the value that you are getting is "Intesept" Casesensitive

also your if didnt work so I've removed it