# bind manual input value and report deviation into the other input column

Tags: jquery, user-input

this question continue my first question about
[how to make function which related comboboxes option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560313/how-to-make-function-which-related-comboboxes-option)

first the input constans so i made function like this

```
$("#pkategori").change(function () {
    var kategori = $("#pkategori").val();
    if (kategori == "TCA"){
        $("#quantity").val("120");      
    }
    if (kategori == "BULK PACK"){
        $("#quantity").val("32");
 }
});
```

completely my code like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nmzJZ/)

but sometime user manually input on "Nomor Seri Produk".
my problem: how to bind what the user write manually on "Nomor Seri Produk" and show deviance on "Quantity".
for example: user manually write on BULK PACK category 1-20 so on quantity automaticly filled by 20

Comment: Do you want to disable the ability to manually input values into the field? If I understand your question correctly, it seems like the easiest method would be to restrict user input to a predefined set of values.

Comment: No. user can manually input.

Comment: What do you mean by "show deviance"?

Comment: manually input by user 1-20
deviance = (20-1)+1 =20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#seri").on("keyup", function() {
    var input = $(this).val();
    var matches = input.match(/(\d+)-(\d+)$/);
    if (matches) {
        var deviance = matches[2]-matches[1]+1;
        $("#quantity").val(deviance);
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/nmzJZ/2/)

Comment: great!!! can you explain meaning of this var matches = input.match(/(\d+)-(\d+)$/);